# Graphing the usage of legal precedents

Tags: data-visualization, graph-theory, java, legal

I would like to hear recommendations on what tools to use to graph the usage of precedents in a legal court in Brazil. The data is searchable at www.stj.jus.br/SCON/, and in the most recent collegiate decisions ('acórdão') database, a field ('Veja') is provided listing the cited cases.

My objective would be to graph those relationships, trying to find often repeated cases and such.
The dataset is relatively big, for courts anyways: about 30k collegiate decisions per year, 300k by 'single judges'. But it could be sliced to be smaller.
From what I've seen, Gephi would be capable of doing this, is there a better alternative? I have about 8 months to complete the project, and have some help from a java programmer, and probably will have to learn a lot of this by myself.

Comment: "Trying to find often repeated cases and such" seems like a very limited and vague objective. Could you be a little more expansive about what kinds of "relationships" you are looking at and what the project aims to accomplish?

Comment: What I meant by the example was to use the graphs to try and find 'central' decisions. Often only the most recent case is cited but in fact that instance is just a repetition. Argument lines can end up split, but have the same origin. Evidencing this 'burial' would be relevant. The idea is to have the visualization as a kind of map to better understand the court's practices, and with that inform what I can persue. I understand now it's a two way road: as I figure capabilities, I might change the objectives.

Comment: I'm not quite clear about the goals, either, but for a network that large I wouldn't rely on traditional network visualizations to reach any conclusions. If you're looking for software recommendations, try Pajek, igraph, or SNAP.